Create column type of ARRAY<JSON> in Snowflake
Im trying to move from BQ to Snowflake but I have a problem creating my table schema.
I have a in BQ columns defined as:
ARRAY<STRUCT<name STRING, id STRING>>

But I didnt find how to do the same in Snowflake.
I have read both docs:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/migration/snowflake-sql
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-structured#label-structured-types-specifying-map
And I dont understand how to do it.

Can you give some examples of what you want the data to look like and what it currently is?

I agree with Mike.
Are you looking for something like:
[{"name": "foo", "id":1}, {"name": "bar", "id":2}]
Maybe this article will help: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured

Snowflake doesn't support STRUCTs outside of Iceberg tables. You can use VARIANTs, but Snowflake won't enforce the schema.

VARIANT holds both JSON and ARRAY's thus, an ARRAY of JSON is still VARIANT.
What it does not do is type/shape inforcement. It is just an anything type.
So some data turned into VARIANT via PARSE_JSON:
select 
    $1 as str,
    PARSE_JSON(str) as json,
    TYPEOF(json) as type,
    SYSTEM$TYPEOF(json) as sys_type
from values
    ('["arrray","of","string"]'), /* array of string */
    ('{"name": "foo", "id":1}'), /* plan JS Object */
    ('[{"name": "foo", "id":1}, {"name": "bar", "id":2}]') /* array of plan JS Object */
;


Here you can see Snowflake know if the object is an ARRAY or OBJECT at the top level, but the column type is VARIANT.
So if you want to have a table that has your array of object, you would use
